# How to mock methods with lambda as parameter

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm new to mocking, I have a method which takes a lambda as a parameter, how can I mock it using Rhino Mocks? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These may help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90851/is-it-just-me-or-are-interfaces-overused

[Mocking method results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90657/mocking-method-results)

Comment: Well that wasnt really what I was looking for, anybody else has any comments?